adding a REWRITE rule in IIS ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
asp.net 4.7 (yeah, it's one of those projects)
iis 10.0.* whatever
client wants few pages on different domain, so we create a new DNS name, point it to old site.
he wants:

newsite.com/page1 to rewrite to oldsite.com/pageA
newsite.com/page2 to rewrite to oldsite.com/pageB

so, for first case, i have a fairly simple rewrite rule:
<rule name="testrewrite" stopProcessing="true"> 
  <match url="page1$" /> 
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?newsite\.com$" /> 
    </conditions> 
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://oldsite.com/pageA" /> 
</rule> 

and this results in TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.
Please note that REDIRECTS work normally, as expected.
made sure redirect module is installed.
there aren't any rules that might contest with the new one. the newsite.com domain is not mentioned anywhere else. also, there's stopProcessing, and the rewrite rule is handled first

A rewrite rule alone won't give you that, so you have to carefully analyze all redirection responses you got and see what else is there. There are often redirection from the web apps themselves, as well as other rules on the server. Besides, use a privacy tab of the browser to eliminate caching. Quite a lot to be done before moving further.

Try clearing your browser's cache and cookies and then restart your browser and visit it
